# Saving a JQuery sortable list with Backbone save?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js, underscore.js-templating

My backbone code, see below, is working without any issues, it gets the data and displays / renders that data using an underscore template. I have also add a trigger event to the backbone code, so that it gets JQuery to sort the template data into a sortable list.

However I have tried to update my sortable list with an update callback, which is meant to take the updated order of my list, convert it to JSON data, then using Backbone.save(); to save the data to my database.

My Backbone data ::

```
  var AdminColModel = Backbone.Collection.extend({
     url: '/Admin/GetMenuData'
  });

  var AdminEditMenu = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $(".page"),
  render: function() {
      var that = this;
      var MyMenu = new AdminColModel(); 
      MyMenu.fetch({
        success: function(MyMenu) {
            var menutemp = _.template( $('script.MenuTemplate').html(), {MyMenu: MyMenu.toJSON() } );
            that.$el.html(menutemp);
            that.trigger('MenuSortableList', that); <- fires my sort list!  
        }
      });
  } //End of render function
   });

   $(document).ready(function(){  
     var MyMenu = new AdminEditMenu();
     MyMenu.on('MenuSortableList', function(event) { 
        $( "#AdminChangeMenuOrder" ).sortable({
        axis: 'y',
        placeholder: 'AdminMenuChangeableList',
        helper: "clone",
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        forceHelperSize: true,
        cursor: "move",
        update: function() {
            var sortableLinks = $(".AdminMenuChangeableList");
            $(sortableLinks).sortable();
            var linkOrderData = $(sortableLinks).sortable('serialize');
            console.log(linkOrderData); 
            linkOrderData.save();
        }
         });
     });
     MyMenu.render();  
   });
```

Now this all works, apart from the code within the 'update' section call within the sortable call.

This is my underscore template,

```
 <script class="MenuTemplate" type="text/template"> 
    <section id="AdminChangeMenuOrder">
        <% _.each(MyMenu, function(MyMenu) { %> 
            <div id="<%= MyMenu.id %>" class="AdminMenuChangeableList"><%= MyMenu.title %> @ <%= MyMenu.path %> Current Level : <%= MyMenu.level %></div>
        <% }); %>
    </section>
 </script>
```

Now the template works, but I have been doing some research and it looks like a lot of people, use  `li`  lists, is that what I should do with my template, is that easy to convert to a JSON object?

All help most welcome,

Thanks

Glenn

Comment: Ok, I am a little more forward, this is what I now have in my update call, var Data = $(this).sortable('toArray');console.log(Data); - this seems to work fine, it returns all the IDs in there current list order after its has been changed. I am still not sure how to get this into a JSON format with the LEVELS in there and then get Backbone to save it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have this all working now. First I had to convert the JQuery sortable list into JSON format, then set it up in a backbone model and save that model, I am not sure if this is the right way about doing it, but it does work.

Where is the 'update' section of my sortable list which is what I have change,

```
        update: function() {
            var i = 1;
            var Data = $(this).sortable('toArray');
            _.each(Data, function(Data) { 
                var UpdatedMenuList = new Backbone.Model({ id: Data, level: i++ });
                UpdatedMenuList.url = '/Admin/UpdateMenuData';
                UpdatedMenuList.save(); 
            });
        }
```

If anyone thinks this is wrong, then please let me know and how best to change my code.

Thanks

Glenn.